# Using a geo plugin in php I was able to redirect visitors from different countries, but I have seem to messed something up, can't locate what it is

Tags: php

my country code is NL and I have setup a piece of code using the geoscript plugin in php to redirect visitors from my country and some others to a different link.

All the other traffic goes to another link.

This used to work great just a few days ago, but I have made some alternations and now it keeps sending people to the "other" link.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$country_codes = array('US', 'CA', 'GB', 'AU', 'NZ', 'ZA', 'NL');

$main_traffic = array(
"LINK1",
"LINK2"
);

$other_traffic = array(
"LINK3"
);


require_once('geoplugin.class.php');
$geoplugin = new geoPlugin();
$geoplugin->locate();
$var_country_code = $geoplugin->countryCode;

if (in_array($var_country_code, $country_codes)) {

header("refresh: 0.1; url=" .$main_traffic[array_rand($main_traffic)]);
}
else {
header("refresh: 0.1; url=" .$other_traffic[array_rand($other_traffic)]);
}
?>
```

Again the script keeps sending me to $other_traffic (LINK3)

I tried to retrace my steps but can't find anything wrong with the above code..
Hopeless at this point, if someone can point at what I am doing wrong, I'll be very thankful!